# How to parse this JSON in dart?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization

I am trying to parse the following JSON in dart but whenever I run my get method I received nothing in my userPosts object. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.
I created the following model class using app.quicktype.io

**This is the JSON that I am trying to parse.**

```
[
    {
      "_id": "5eedd6ee16bec833275bc929",
      "caption": "Test",
      "postImages": "",
      "postVideos": "",
      "postAudio": "",
      "postSharedBy": [
        ""
      ],
      "tag": [
        {
          "userId": "",
          "name": "",
          "guruzziId": ""
        }
      ],
      "location": "",
      "locationLatLong": [
        ""
      ],
      "anonymous": false,
      "flagInappropriate": [
        ""
      ],
      "likes": [
        ""
      ],
      "userId": "5eedbd19996dc053453ff24c",
      "createdAt": "2020-06-20 09:29:18",
      "updatedAt": "2020-06-20 09:29:18",
      "status": true,
      "userDetail": {
        "_id": "5eedbd19996dc053453ff24c",
        "guruzziId": "_bxgza1vgw",
        "firstName": "Archit Arora",
        "lastName": "",
        "photoUrl": ""
      }
    }
  ]
```

**This is the Modal that I created**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

List<Post> postFromJson(String str) {
  return List<Post>.from(jsonDecode(str).map((x) => Post.fromJson(x)));
}

String postToJson(List<Post> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Post {
  Post({
    this.id,
    this.caption,
    this.postImages,
    this.postVideos,
    this.postAudio,
    this.postSharedBy,
    this.tag,
    this.location,
    this.locationLatLong,
    this.anonymous,
    this.flagInappropriate,
    this.likes,
    this.userId,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.status,
    this.userDetail,
  });

  String id;
  String caption;
  String postImages;
  String postVideos;
  String postAudio;
  List<String> postSharedBy;
  List<Tag> tag;
  String location;
  List<String> locationLatLong;
  bool anonymous;
  List<String> flagInappropriate;
  List<String> likes;
  String userId;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  bool status;
  UserDetail userDetail;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      id: json["_id"],
    caption: json["caption"],
    postImages: json["postImages"],
    postVideos: json["postVideos"],
    postAudio: json["postAudio"],
    postSharedBy: List<String>.from(json["postSharedBy"].map((x) => x)),
    tag: List<Tag>.from(json["tag"].map((x) => Tag.fromJson(x))),
    location: json["location"],
    locationLatLong: List<String>.from(json["locationLatLong"].map((x) => x)),
    anonymous: json["anonymous"],
    flagInappropriate: List<String>.from(json["flagInappropriate"].map((x) => x)),
    likes: List<String>.from(json["likes"].map((x) => x)),
    userId: json["userId"],
    createdAt: json["createdAt"],
    updatedAt: json["updatedAt"],
    status: json["status"],
    userDetail: UserDetail.fromJson(json["userDetail"]),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "caption": caption,
        "postImages": postImages,
        "postVideos": postVideos,
        "postAudio": postAudio,
        "postSharedBy": List<dynamic>.from(postSharedBy.map((x) => x)),
        "tag": List<dynamic>.from(tag.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "location": location,
        "locationLatLong": List<dynamic>.from(locationLatLong.map((x) => x)),
        "anonymous": anonymous,
        "flagInappropriate":
            List<dynamic>.from(flagInappropriate.map((x) => x)),
        "likes": List<dynamic>.from(likes.map((x) => x)),
        "userId": userId,
        "createdAt": createdAt,
        "updatedAt": updatedAt,
        "status": status,
        "userDetail": userDetail.toJson(),
      };
}

class Tag {
  Tag({
    this.userId,
    this.name,
    this.guruzziId,
  });

  String userId;
  String name;
  String guruzziId;

  factory Tag.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Tag(
        userId: json["userId"],
        name: json["name"],
        guruzziId: json["guruzziId"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "userId": userId,
        "name": name,
        "guruzziId": guruzziId,
      };
}

class UserDetail {
  UserDetail({
    this.id,
    this.guruzziId,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.photoUrl,
  });

  String id;
  String guruzziId;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String photoUrl;

  factory UserDetail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserDetail(
        id: json["_id"],
        guruzziId: json["guruzziId"],
        firstName: json["firstName"],
        lastName: json["lastName"],
        photoUrl: json["photoUrl"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "guruzziId": guruzziId,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "photoUrl": photoUrl,
      };
}
```

**This is the GET method where the code is breaking**

```
static Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get('$_url/post?userId=$_userId');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
        List<Post> userPosts = postFromJson(data.toString());
      } else {
        return List<Post>();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return List<Post>();
    }
  }
```

**Response Body**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "5eedd6ee16bec833275bc929",
      "caption": "Test",
      "postImages": "",
      "postVideos": "",
      "postAudio": "",
      "postSharedBy": [
        ""
      ],
      "tag": [
        {
          "userId": "",
          "name": "",
          "guruzziId": ""
        }
      ],
      "location": "",
      "locationLatLong": [
        ""
      ],
      "anonymous": false,
      "flagInappropriate": [
        ""
      ],
      "likes": [
        ""
      ],
      "userId": "5eedbd19996dc053453ff24c",
      "createdAt": "2020-06-20 09:29:18",
      "updatedAt": "2020-06-20 09:29:18",
      "status": true,
      "userDetail": {
        "_id": "5eedbd19996dc053453ff24c",
        "guruzziId": "_bxgza1vgw",
        "firstName": "Archit Arora",
        "lastName": "",
        "photoUrl": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "error": false,
  "message": "Success",
  "code": 200
}
```

Comment: What is the point of this line `var data = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];`? Are your JSON inside another JSON object? If so, please provide the value of `response.body`.

Comment: @julemand101 I have added the response.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the response you get is not a JSON which contains a JSON represented as a String. Instead, the whole response is a combined JSON so you don't need to parse it two times.

I have created the following which shows what you need to do. `json` is a String with the value of the "Response body" you have provided. I have also included `postFromJson` since I have made a change there:

```
void main() {
  dynamic data = jsonDecode(json)['data'];
  List<Post> userPosts = postFromJson(data);
  userPosts.forEach((x) => print(x.toJson())); // just to show each object
}

List<Post> postFromJson(List<dynamic> postJsonObjs) {
  return List<Post>.from(postJsonObjs.map((x) => Post.fromJson(x)));
}
```